# Alterar o xml pelo java

Tags: java, android, xml, include

Queria saber se existe um jeito de eu alterar o `layout="@layout/app_bar_main"` do `<include>` pelo java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Se preferir, você pode tentar esse jeito: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18999694/4508758

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente é necessário incluir um `id` ao seu `<include>`.

```
 <include
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Depois você pode fazer desta forma usando o `LayoutInflater`:

```
RelativeLayout main= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_container); 
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.seu_layout, null);
main.removeAllViews();
main.addView(layout);
```

No entanto, usar o `ViewStub` nesta situação, pode ser mais vantajoso que o `<include>`. Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```
<ViewStub
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:inflatedId="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Sendo assim na classe:

```
ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.main_container);
stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.seu_layout);
View inflated = stub.inflate();
```